# Can a category have heterogeneous arrows?

Tags: category-theory

For example, **Poset** has objects all posets and morphisms that preserve structure. Can the arrows be different operations? An example?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no restrictions on what the arrows in a category can be, as long as the axioms are satisfied. Since you mentioned posets, any poset $P$ itself gives rise to a category. Its objects are the elements in $P$ and an arrow $f:x\to y$ exists in the category (and is just a symbol, i.e., the symbol $f_{xy}$), precisely when $x\le y$.